# derivative of a function

Tags: r, derivative

I am using D to get derivatives of a function. However, R does not simplify the expression when returning the derivative. I need to figure out if a function has a derivative that can be expressed generically. Is there some way in R to simplify the expression?

```
> D(expression(sqrt(1 - x^2)), 'x')
-(0.5 * (2 * x * (1 - x^2)^-0.5))
> D(D(expression(sqrt(1 - x^2)), 'x'), 'x')
-(0.5 * (2 * (1 - x^2)^-0.5 - 2 * x * (-0.5 * (2 * x * (1 - x^2)^-1.5))))
```

Secondly, is there a way in R to do numerical integration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x")
Simplify(deriv(sqrt(1 - x^2),x,2))  # return the result simplified
```

gives

```
expression((x^2 - 1 - x^2)/root(1 - x^2, 2)^3)
```

You can also try

```
PrettyForm(Simplify(deriv(sqrt(1 - x^2),x,2)))
```

which gives

```
   2        2  
  x  - 1 - x   
---------------
              3
    /      2 \ 
Sqrt\ 1 - x  /
```

As for numerical integration try giving this to see what is available

```
library(sos)
findFn('{numerical+integration}')
```

Comment: this is really helpful. it makes searching functions so much easier!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, R will not simplify the result of `D()`. It sounds as though you want a proper computer algebra system, and R is definitely not a full CAS. [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com) and [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com) are the most well-known, but there are also a number of open-source alternatives ([as discussed on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550/best-open-source-mathematica-equivalent)).

R can do numerical integration - for this kind of question it is worth searching in the R help pages first (i.e. `help.search('integrate')`). You can use `integrate()` in the `stats` package. There is also `area()` in the `MASS` package, but that is much simpler (i.e. for demonstration purposes).

Comment: R symbolic capabilities can be extended with Ryacas or rSymPy.